# Docker busybox exit immediately

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, busybox

I am trying to create a busybox docker image to save the logs of my rails application, including nginx and unicorn logs. In order to create that container, I use the following command:

```
docker run --name app-logs -v /logs busybox /bin/sh
```

However the created container exits immediately with the code 0:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                              NAMES
75e2f2efdc77        busybox             "/bin/sh"                6 seconds ago       Exited (0) 4 seconds ago                                      app-logs
```

The command docker logs is not giving any output and I can't find out what the problem is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [run docker in the foreground](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground) if you want to use a shell.

```
-t=false        : Allocate a pseudo-tty
-i=false        : Keep STDIN open even if not attached
```

So

```
docker run -ti --name app-logs -v /logs busybox /bin/sh
```

#### Data + Volumes

If you want to keep a what's called a [data volume container](http://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container), you need to have at least one container that has a reference to the volume. There's no need to keep it running. An exited container is still saved on your system (`docker ps -a`).

```
docker run --name app-logs -v /logs busybox /bin/true
```

Then you can mount your data container volume from your app containers

```
 docker run -d --volumes-from app-logs --name app busybox ruby yourapp.rb
```

The other way to achieve the same is to use the host to store the data by mounting a host volume everywhere

```
docker run --name app -v /logs:/logs busybox ruby yourapp.rb
```

I've found storing data on the host outside of docker to be beneficial when dockers storage has issues. I can blow all the docker data away and start again and easily keep and re mount all my stateful/app data that's stored on the host.

Comment: I want to keep it opened but not running it in the foreground. Is it possible to do it?. If not, how can I find the reason about why it is closing immediately?

Comment: You probably don't want to be running `sh` then. Are you using some type of syslog process to collect the logs?

Comment: I have configured nginx, unicorn and rails to use /logs and I want to keep that logs if there happens any problem. For this, I consirer to use a busybox to keep it safe. Is not necessary to be running sh for that?

Comment: Oh I see.  You don't need a running container. I've included some volume notes.